# Why Is My Flow Re-running After I Throw An Exception?

Tags: corda

I have a flow (without a responder) that does some validations and calls a sub-flow on success.
During the validation I query the vault for states and should only get 1 state back.
If I get more than 1 state back I throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

When I look in the logs, this exception has been thrown multiple times and there are multiple stacktraces indicating that the flow has been run multiple times.
However, if I log an error instead of throwing an exception the flow only gets run once.

Why does throwing an exception cause the flow to be run multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know why this could be happening based on what you've described here, but make sure that you're not calling subflows like FinalityFlow and then trying to do other things after.

```
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SIGNING);
        SignedTransaction signedTransaction = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder);
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(FINALISING);
        SignedTransaction fullySignedTransaction = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(signedTransaction, singletonList(session)));
        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTransaction, singletonList(session)));
    }
```

source: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/secretsanta-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/secretsanta/flows/CreateSantaSessionFlow.java#L82

The last thing most flows do is return a subflow, if you try to do other things after that can be done but it often leads to outcomes people aren't expecting.

Also make sure to add the @suspendable,(just in case you didn't have that) that might be causing some breaking as corda would end up running your flow a bunch of times.